# Imacros click selector

Tags: imacros

I'm a beginner in imacros.

```
FRAME F=1
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(5)>SPAN" BUTTON=0

EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>SPAN" BUTTON=0

EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(6)>SPAN" BUTTON=0

EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>SPAN" BUTTON=0

EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>SPAN" BUTTON=0

EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV>SPAN" BUTTON=0
```

I have them all in 6 different saved macros with the frame f=1, is there a simpler way to make it click all of them from just 1 saved macros command instead of 6?, it be much easier if I can make it click with just one command ...like one command would work to click any of the 6 random ones? maybe I need to shorten one of them and it would work to click any of them?

and it's to make it click as fast as it goes so putting all 6 click commands into one will run but it'll click slower do to clicking the right one all the time, just wondering if i can put just one command would make it click regardless which 6 command it is.

Comment: if i put all 6 into one , by the time it hits the correct one to go, it be to slow, ... preferbly at a speed of 45ms be nice ill try kantuu best to try all i can lol

Answer (score 0):

Try this macro having only one line:

```
URL GOTO=javascript:{for(i=1;i<=6;i++)window.frames[0].document.querySelector("HTML>BODY>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type("+i+")>SPAN").click();}
```

('iMacros for Firefox' **v.8.9.7**)

Comment: that code you made kinda worked but it froze up kinda like a security thing, its for doing this mission on a game and what i copy pastes works , i dunno if its do to speed is why it work, yours started but froze my game, or else that be perfect lol

Comment: sugar if you can email me at joyrock0121@outlook.com, id gladly show you what its doing , my links seem to work, yours froze up like a security thing, it clicked just once, the macros kept going but it froze me up lmao, if you can help me out further that be great, ill show you a clip of what its doing if you want to help me better :), thanks for the help i think im almost there lol

Comment: If the suggested code just clicks once, try to add a small pause after it. For example: `WAIT SECONDS=3` or even `PAUSE` for better debugging.

Comment: it detects the javascript right away, like them 6 random links if i put them in 6 different macros and i know wich one will work, itll click, no wait time no pause it goes as fast as it goes, it detects the javascript right away, so maybe ill just need to keep guessing wich one to use each time , the event click selector is the only way to get it to click, if it wasnt for that java detection  ...what you made would be perfect,

Comment: and what you did does work i see it click as many times needed, just gets detected right away instantly , kinda weird they never detected them click events link i posted lmao